# Cannot run cypress with a fresh yarn pnp install

Tags: cypress, hadoop-yarn, yarn-v2

I'm trying to setup Cypress with jest adapter and testing-library/cypress but I'm encountering an issue as I'm using Yarn Pnp. Here I tried to do it in a fresh project.

```
mkdir test-cypress && cd test-cypress
yarn init
yarn add react react-dom vite
yarn add cypress --dev
yarn run cypress open
```

And I get an error,

> Error: Your application tried to access @opentelemetry/resources, but
> it isn't declared in your dependencies; this make s the require call
> ambiguous and unsound.
>
> Required package: @opentelemetry/resources (via
> "@opentelemetry/resources") Required by:
> /Users/Saud/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.17.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/telemetry/dist/

My package.json file,

```
{ "name": "new-cypress", "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.0", "dependencies": { "react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", "vite": "^4.4.2" }, "devDependencies": { "cypress": "12.17.1" } }
```

If I do it via npm, it works fine. The problem is somehow related to Yarn pnp. Note that I've tried downgrading cypress to v10 and v9. The same error occurs just for a different library. So in v10 I get required "lodash" and in v9 for "graceful-fs"